# Maven, ways to allocate common steps in Profiles

Tags: java, maven

I have situation with my POM.xml like this:

```
... 
<profiles>
  <profile>     
     -some actions B
     -some common for both profiles actions
  </profile>
  <profile>
     -some actions A
     -some common for both profiles actions
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Which ways can I use to take out the common actions to avoid copy/paste?

After that, how can I identify in my Java code which profile executes now?

I need this because the code is pretty common for both profiles, I can't separate it, so I want to create some condition in my java code, where I'll be able to choose further actions according to current Profile. I've tried to use SystemProperty configuration in my pom.xml by It was unsuccessful, I wasn't able to get this property by System.getProperty(..) and also I doubt that this is a good way.

Comment: the way maven profiles work is totally screwed up. the only sensible way to do this is to add one profile per functionality and calling maven with a list of profiles. sorry, I've been hammering my head against that for years

Comment: Thanks...but what about second part of question? Are there any other ways to make condition in Java code according to the current running Profile?

Comment: if you have access to the `MavenProject` object, use [`getActiveProfiles()`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject.html#getActiveProfiles%28%29)

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd, thanks, but if I haven't such access, is there any other way..?

Comment: What kind of commond action are you talking about? Can you show a pom example what you like to achieve ?